# JavaScript - Running a forEach in array of objects. Would like to check a substring in a string and replace it with a new substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

In JavaScript, I am running a forEch method on an array of objects. Would like to run through my JSON and replace a substring in a string with a new string if the condition is met.

The issue is this: http://www.bucketfeet.comhttps://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/media/artist/d/a/daniel_falsetta_headshot.jpg AND undefined.

Here is the code with JSON data. Thanks for your help in advance. Here is the repl link as well- https://repl.it/BQsZ/19 so you can run the code.

```
var dataJson = [{
    "created_at": "2015-03-27 11:08:00+00:00",
    "city": "Pueblo",
    "first_name": "daniel",
    "last_name": "Falsetta",
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 6709,
    "email": "8XC87gZdjX92@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "https://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/media/artist/d/a/daniel_falsetta_headshot.jpg"
},{
    "created_at": "2015-03-27 11:08:00+00:00",
    "city": "Dallas",
    "first_name": "Suah",
    "last_name": "Yu",
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 6708,
    "email": "BATJP3mht4vd@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": ""
},{
    "created_at": "2015-03-27 11:08:00+00:00",
    "city": "Ottawa ",
    "first_name": "Makena",
    "last_name": "Ablett",
    "country": "CA",
    "artist_id": 6710,
    "email": "RTFheqUbixmy@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/image-4414.jpg"
},{
    "created_at": "2015-03-27 10:53:40+00:00",
    "city": "Pittsburgh",
    "first_name": "Michelle",
    "last_name": "Vecchio",
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 7388,
    "email": "kpEFwMqV0Zip@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "http://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/media/artist/i/m/image_473.jpg"
}, {
    "created_at": "2015-03-26 18:13:45+00:00",
    "city": "",
    "first_name": "Wendy",
    "last_name": "Slavas",
    "country": "",
    "artist_id": 28,
    "email": "aHrDLA3W5a6p@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": ""
}
];


var profUrlFunc = function() {
    var objTableArray = dataJson;

    objTableArray.forEach(function(user) {
        var httpsLinkCloudFront = "https://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net"; //length: 37
        var httpLinkCloudFront = "http://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net"; //length: 36
        var prefixLink = "http://www.bucketfeet.com";
        var placeHolderForLink = user.profile_image_url;

        if(user.profile_image_url) {
                    //if user profile image has HTTP /cloudfront prefix link remove it and add http://www.bucketfeet.com OR don't add anything
                     user.profile_image_url = placeHolderForLink.replace("http://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net", "www.bucketfeet.com")
                }
                if (user.profile_image_url) {
                    //if user profile image has HTTPS /cloudfront prefix link remove it and add http://www.bucketfeet.com OR don't add anything
                    user.profile_image_url = placeHolderForLink.replace("https://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net", "www.bucketfeet.com")
                }
                if (user.profile_image_url) {
                    //if no prefix(broken link:/media/artist/image-4414.jpg) add http://www.bucketfeet.com
                    var newModifiedLinkUrl = prefixLink.concat(placeHolderForLink)
                    user.profile_image_url = newModifiedLinkUrl;
                    console.log(user.profile_image_url);
                }
                else {
                    //if it is empty give it a default image
                    user.profile_image_url = "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
                }
    });
 };

console.log(profUrlFunc());
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Alexander if you console the code on repl (link above) I get this http://www.bucketfeet.comhttps://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/media/artist/d/a/daniel_falsetta_headshot.jpg AND undefined. I can't seem to fix that.

Comment: are you know that first two `if block` a same?

Comment: @Grundy one is with HTTP and the other one is HTTPS. I don't know how to check two conditions at the same time on replace method.

Comment: @Mihir Patel you get `undefined` because your function `profUrlFunc` does not return anything and by default in JS it is `undefined`, return from function what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/djj2q7av/ as you can see there is not `undefined`

Comment: @Alexander I will fix that. But how about the issue when I am getting a prepend link like this- http://www.bucketfeet.comhttps://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/media/artist/d/a/daniel_falsetta_headshot.jpg. I want to remove https://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net.

Comment: :-D missed that, but anyway you can avoid it with a bit change `if(user.profile_image_url) {
                        //if user profile image has HTTP /cloudfront prefix link remove it and add http://www.bucketfeet.com OR don't add anything
                         user.profile_image_url = placeHolderForLink.replace("https?://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net", "www.bucketfeet.com")
                    }`

Comment: @grundy do you mind providing in fiddle or in a code block. Hard to read.

Comment: @MihirPatel sure, wait a minute

Comment: @Alexander I created a jsbin for you -https://jsbin.com/gegupetoxu/edit?js,console

Comment: @MihirPatel, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r5dwpymo/ , seems i confused string and regex :-)

Comment: @grundy This solution works. Can you mind explaining regex piece of the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a bit simplified your function:
first, you have same url for cloud front except protocol part, `replace` function availabe regex as first parameter.

```
/https?:\/\/d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/
```

this regex say that `s` in part `https` is optional, so this regex match both url with http and with https.

second, you should check that `placeHolderForLink` already not start from `prefixLink` before add it.

So you can get something like this:

```
var profUrlFunc = function () {
    var objTableArray = dataJson;

    objTableArray.forEach(function (user) {
        var LinkCloudFront = /https?:\/\/d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/;
        var prefixLink = "http://www.bucketfeet.com";
        var placeHolderForLink = user.profile_image_url;

        if (placeHolderForLink) {

            placeHolderForLink = placeHolderForLink.replace(LinkCloudFront, prefixLink);
            if (!placeHolderForLink.startsWith(prefixLink)) {
                placeHolderForLink = prefixLink.concat(placeHolderForLink);
            }
        } else {
            //if it is empty give it a default image
            placeHolderForLink = "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
        }
        user.profile_image_url = placeHolderForLink;
    });
};
```

```js
var dataJson = [{
    "created_at": "2015-03-27 11:08:00+00:00",
        "city": "Pueblo",
        "first_name": "daniel",
        "last_name": "Falsetta",
        "country": "US",
        "artist_id": 6709,
        "email": "8XC87gZdjX92@example.com",
        "profile_image_url": "https://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/media/artist/d/a/daniel_falsetta_headshot.jpg"
}, {
    "created_at": "2015-03-27 11:08:00+00:00",
        "city": "Dallas",
        "first_name": "Suah",
        "last_name": "Yu",
        "country": "US",
        "artist_id": 6708,
        "email": "BATJP3mht4vd@example.com",
        "profile_image_url": ""
}, {
    "created_at": "2015-03-27 11:08:00+00:00",
        "city": "Ottawa ",
        "first_name": "Makena",
        "last_name": "Ablett",
        "country": "CA",
        "artist_id": 6710,
        "email": "RTFheqUbixmy@example.com",
        "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/image-4414.jpg"
}, {
    "created_at": "2015-03-27 10:53:40+00:00",
        "city": "Pittsburgh",
        "first_name": "Michelle",
        "last_name": "Vecchio",
        "country": "US",
        "artist_id": 7388,
        "email": "kpEFwMqV0Zip@example.com",
        "profile_image_url": "http://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/media/artist/i/m/image_473.jpg"
}, {
    "created_at": "2015-03-26 18:13:45+00:00",
        "city": "",
        "first_name": "Wendy",
        "last_name": "Slavas",
        "country": "",
        "artist_id": 28,
        "email": "aHrDLA3W5a6p@example.com",
        "profile_image_url": ""
}];


var profUrlFunc = function () {
    var objTableArray = dataJson;

    objTableArray.forEach(function (user) {
        var LinkCloudFront = /https?:\/\/d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net/;
        var prefixLink = "http://www.bucketfeet.com";
        var placeHolderForLink = user.profile_image_url;

        if (placeHolderForLink) {

            placeHolderForLink = placeHolderForLink.replace(LinkCloudFront, prefixLink);
            if (!placeHolderForLink.startsWith(prefixLink)) {
                placeHolderForLink = prefixLink.concat(placeHolderForLink);
            }
        } else {
            //if it is empty give it a default image
            placeHolderForLink = "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
        }
        user.profile_image_url = placeHolderForLink;
    });
};
profUrlFunc();
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dataJson.map(function (el) {
    return el.profile_image_url
}), null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var profUrlFunc = function() {
  var objTableArray = dataJson;

  objTableArray.forEach(function(user) {
    var httpsLinkCloudFront = "https://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net";
    var httpLinkCloudFront = "http://d153fwbf2sefnf.cloudfront.net";
    var prefixLink = "http://www.bucketfeet.com";
    var placeHolderForLink = user.profile_image_url;
    var condition = new RegExp([httpsLinkCloudFront, httpLinkCloudFront].join('|'));

    if (user.profile_image_url) {
      if (!condition.test(user.profile_image_url)) {
        user.profile_image_url = prefixLink + user.profile_image_url;
      } else {
        user.profile_image_url = user.profile_image_url.replace(condition, prefixLink);
      }
    } else {
      user.profile_image_url = "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
    }
  });

  return objTableArray;
};
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/djj2q7av/1/)

Answer (score -1):

in forEach

```
if(placeHolderForLink && placeHolderForLink.length) {
user.profile_image_url = (!placeHolderForLink.indexof(httpsLinkCloudFront)) ? 
                                           prefixLink+placeHolderForLink.substr(placeHolderForLink.indexOf(httpsLinkCloudFront)+37)
                                          :(!placeHolderForLink.indexof(httpLinkCloudFront)) ? 
                                            prefixLink+placeHolderForLink.substr(placeHolderForLink.indexOf(httpLinkCloudFront)+36)
                                           : 
                                           prefixLink+placeHolderForLink
}
```

or, readable and maintainable:

```
if (placeHolderForLink && placeHolderForLink.length) {
    if (!placeHolderForLink.indexof(httpsLinkCloudFront)) {
      var1 = prefixLink+placeHolderForLink.substr(placeHolderForLink.indexOf(httpsLinkCloudFront)+37)
    } elsif (!placeHolderForLink.indexof(httpLinkCloudFront)) {
      var1 = prefixLink+placeHolderForLink.substr(placeHolderForLink.indexOf(httpLinkCloudFront)+36)
    } else {
      var1 = prefixLink+placeHolderForLink
    }
    user.profile_image_url =  var1
}
```

Comment: for the audience at home: don't ever write code this way.  Also, OP, please describe how your solution works, and what the Asker's problem was vai your deduction.

Comment: ^ I agree.  don't understand this solution. Not it works.

Comment: js has not operator `elsif` :-)